# n parameters in htaccess mod-rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a rewrite rule that can handle any number of arguments, for example:

localhost/1/2/3/4/5/6/...

Is it possible to write a rewrite rule for this? There´s no problem to collect them all in one parameter with braces to get PHP to handle them as a array if that would help.

Kind Regards

Comment: Look at `[N]` flag -- if you build your rewrite rule **properly** (which is quite tricky to do) you will be able to achieve what you want -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is going to look something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*(/[^/]*)*)$ localhost?index.php?var=$1
```

You'll end up dealing with x/y/z in 'var', but without knowing the number of arguments ahead of time that's the best you can do.

(For clarification, [^/] means "any character except '/'".)